# Replicating the behavior of a web deployment project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment-project

With VS 2012, web deployment projects are out. This is fine, but I cannot find the correct way to replace the functionality they used to provide with the new publishing tools.

I need to be able to compile a web site or web app project then create all of the content and primary output files to a location on disk where they can be packaged by a third party installer (InstallShield for now - soon to be replaced) *that is also part of the solution*.

This also will have to work as part of a Team Build as well as support relative paths.

The closest option to what I think would be appropriate for web applications is the "FileSystem" publish, yet I cannot find out how to invoke that outside of issuing a "publish" command in the VS IDE. Previously I could just select the wdproj in the solution config and it would output the items to the target location with a compile.

There does not seem to be an appropriate path for web site projects.

Can someone explain or link to how this should be setup?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for wdp replacement too, and I found this blog today, have not tried yet

[Visual Studio 2012 Web Deployment Projects are Dead – Long Live Publishing Profiles](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2012/08/26/visual-studio-2012-web-deployment-projects-are-dead-ndash-long-live-publishing-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to this either so I ended up deploying to a folder and adding the folder into the installshield limited edition project. not an ideal solution by any means.